# Очистить число с плавающей точкой от лишнего одним шаблоном регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

на входе имеем `-238.125.861875621`
как дополнить этот шаблон `(^-?\d+[\.,]\d+)`, чтобы вернулось такое `-238.125861875621`?
Т.е. чтобы убралась лишняя точка. Лишних точек или запятых может быть несколько

Comment: На каком языке вам нужно сделать это?

Comment: Само по себе регулярное выражение ничего не удаляет. Для этого существуют специальные методы или функции. Какой вы пользуетесь?

Comment: PHP - мне нужно чтобы в захват попало правильное

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, для **PHP** будет так:

```php
<?php
function callbackFunction( $matches) {
  return $matches[1].preg_replace('/\D/i', '', $matches[2]);
}
$pattern = '/(-?\\d+\\.)([\\s\\S]+)/AD';
$subject = '-238.125.,8618.75,621';
print_r( preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'callbackFunction', $subject, -1 ) );
?>
```

По аналогии на **JS** (интерактивно):

```js
function fNumbClean(obj) {
  var aNumbers = obj.value.split('\n');
  for (let i = 0; i < aNumbers.length; i++) {

    // Собственно, сама замена
    aNumbers[i] = aNumbers[i].replace(/^(-?\d+\.)([\s\S]+)/gi, function(str, p1, p2) {
      return p1 + p2.replace(/\D/gi, '');
    });
    
  }
  document.getElementById('output').value = aNumbers.join('\n');
}
```

```html
<textarea oninput="fNumbClean(this);">-238.125.861875621&#13;&#10;-238.125,861875621&#13;&#10;-238.125.8618,75621&#13;&#10;-238.125.,8618.75,621</textarea><span> > </span><textarea readonly id="output"></textarea><style>textarea{height:4.65em;width:200px;vertical-align:middle;}span{font:4em Arial;color:#ddd;vertical-align:middle;}</style>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но мне хотелось бы узнать возможность организовать это одним шаблоном

Comment: @SanyaH, каким образом вы хотите сделать это?

Comment: @SanyaH , думаю, что это невозможно. Да и большим код кажется только из-за того, что построчно расписан.

Comment: @SanyaH, вот это попробуйте https://ideone.com/ncjsgE